# sforce.one.navigatetourl is not working in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

sforce.one.navigateToURL("https://cs26.lightning.force.com/apex/home");

I have to redirect to home tab but it is not working.

Comment: can you please post the source code or snap code for that particular method/function that you are using for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
sforce.one.navigateToURL('/home/home.jsp',true);
```

Comment: It is not working